# Как решить проблему с запуском VsCode?

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

Устанавливал платины. При установке платина GitLense - программа перестала отвечать. Переустанавливал несколько раз. И теперь каждый раз при запуске появляется эта вкладка Welcome to gitlense и дальше программа не работает. Сможете помочь?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю стоит начать с папки C:\Users\ВашПрофиль.vscode\extensions

Зайдите в эту папку через проводник и удалите папку с плагином GitLense,
запустите VsCode.

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало. Теперь такая же проблема возникает при открытии проекта в IDE. Если что, у меня макбук и линукс на виртуальной машине